# Is it possible to cut a specific column and display the number of repeated occurence from the column in bash script?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, scripting

Text file:

```
Bill Both, 123456789, Computer Information Systems
Carla Carothers, 234567890, Computer Information Systems 
Stephanie Williams, 345678901, Marketing
Aritrya Badopadhi, 456789012, Computer Science
Santhi Roopashree, 567890123, Computer Information Systems
Heather Williams, 678901234, Computer Information Systems
Dave Schroth, 789012345, Computer Science
```

Output I want is:

```
4 Computer Information Systems
2 Computer Science
1 Marketing
```

--
This is my script

```
file=$1
for line in $(cat $file)
do
        echo "$line" | cut -d " "  -f4-6 | uniq -d 
done
exit 0
```

but it's not showing me the repeated occurrence in column 4.

Comment: Is the last line really that long? Does the file contain `"`?

Comment: Also please do mention which field you want to take the count with more clear examples in your question as it is not clear as of now.

Comment: The file does not contain ", and the last line is not supposed to be that long, a new line should start right after the major.

Comment: I want to count column 4 since I want to know how many majors are being repeated. The output I want is: 4 Computer Information Systems
2 Computer Science
1 Marketing

Comment: @donknowhongkong, I have edited your post again(with code tags) kindly check it once and lemme know if data looks good now?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Yes, the date looks much cleaner. Thank you!

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Also, I am using #! /bin/bash, so if that's possible please avoid using awk. Thanks!

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 thank you for your answer, and I prefer using bash instead. What would the script look like if using bash?

Comment: @donknowhongkong, Ok sure, you need NOT to use a for loop for this one, try my EDIT2 code once and lemme know in answer's comment section please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***EDIT2:*** Adding a shell solution as per OP's comment now.

```
FIELD=3
DELMITER=","
cut -d$DELMITER -f $FIELD Input_file | sort| uniq -c |sort -nr
```

Where variable `FIELD` will have field number value, `DELIMITER` is having delimiter's value in it in this case it is `,`(depends upon your data file).`Input_file` is the data file which you are reading here.

---

---

***EDIT:*** Could you please try following. This will provide output in sorted manner.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=","
}
{
  a[$NF]++
}
END{
  for(i in a){
    print a[i],i
  }
}' Input_file  | sort -k2
```

Output will be as follows.

```
4  Computer Information Systems
2  Computer Science
1  Marketing
```

---

---

In case you want to get the output in same order in which last field has come in Input_file, then try following.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=","
}
!b[$NF]++{
  c[++count]=$NF
}
{
  a[$NF]++
}
END{
  for(i=1;i<=count;i++){
    print a[c[i]],c[i]
  }
}' Input_file
```

Comment: the script above works, and how would I put that in the bash script?

Answer (score 1):

You can `cut` the input on `,` as delimeter to extract `-f3` thrid field, then commonly `sort` and count `uniq -c`.

With such recreation of input:

```
cat <<EOF >file.txt
Bill Both, 123456789, Computer Information Systems
Carla Carothers, 234567890, Computer Information Systems
Stephanie Williams, 345678901, Marketing
Aritrya Badopadhi, 456789012, Computer Science
Santhi Roopashree, 567890123, Computer Information Systems
Heather Williams, 678901234, Computer Information Systems
Dave Schroth, 789012345, Computer Science
EOF
```

Such short oneliner:

```
cut -d, -f3 file.txt | sort | uniq -c
```

Outputs:

```
  4  Computer Information Systems
  2  Computer Science
  1  Marketing
```

The additional spaces could be removed with `sed`:

```
cut -d, -f3 file.txt | sort | uniq -c | sed 's/^ *\([0-9]*\) /\1/'
```

which outputs:

```
4 Computer Information Systems
2 Computer Science
1 Marketing
```

Note: The `for line in $(cat)` is a common *anti*-pattern in bash. For [how to read a file line by line in bash](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) use a `while read; do ... done <file` loop.

Comment: So I try while read: but I am still not getting the output that I've stated above. 
while read -r line
do
        echo "$line" | cut -d " "  -f4-6 | uniq -c
done < $file
exit 0

Comment: You need to sort the file for `uniq -c`. To sort the lines, you need to operate on _all_ lines together, not on a single line. With `while read -r line` you operate on a one line at a time. To sort lines in file you need to see all the lines,  well, to compare them together. There is no need to iterate over lines in file here - unix utilities are designed to operate on files, not on lines. just `cut -d " " -f4-6 "$file" | sort | uniq -c` if you wish.